# How to draw fitted graph and actual graph of gamma distribution in one plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics, model-fitting, gamma-distribution

Step.1. Load the package needed.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(MASS)
```

Step.2. Generate 10,000 numbers fitted to gamma distribution.

```
x <- round(rgamma(100000,shape = 2,rate = 0.2),1)
x <- x[which(x>0)]
```

Step.3. Draw the pdf(probability density function), supposed we don't know which distribution `x` fitted to.

```
t1 <- as.data.frame(table(x))
names(t1) <- c("x","y")
t1 <- transform(t1,x=as.numeric(as.character(x)))
t1$y <- t1$y/sum(t1[,2])
ggplot() + geom_point(data = t1,aes(x = x,y = y)) + theme_classic()
```

[image]

Step.4. From the graph, we can learn that the distribution of `x` is quite like gamma distribution, so we use `fitdistr()` in package `MASS` to get the parameters of `shape` and `rate` of gamma distribution.

```
fitdistr(x,"gamma") 
##       output 
##       shape           rate    
##   2.0108224880   0.2011198260 
##  (0.0083543575) (0.0009483429)
```

Step.5. Draw the actual point(black dot) and fitted graph(red line) in the same plot, and here is the question, please look the plot first.

```
ggplot() + geom_point(data = t1,aes(x = x,y = y)) +     
geom_line(aes(x=t1[,1],y=dgamma(t1[,1],2,0.2)),color="red") + 
theme_classic()
```

[image]

Question 1: The real parameters are `shape=2`, `rate=0.2`, and the parameters I use the function `fitdistr()` to get are `shape=2.01`, `rate=0.20`. These two are nearly the same, but why the fitted graph don't fit the actual point well, there must be something wrong in the fitted graph, or the way I draw the fitted graph and actual points is totally wrong, what should I do?

Question 2: After I get the parameter of the model I establish, in which way I evaluate the model, something like `RSS(residual square sum)` for linear model, or the `p-value` of `shapiro.test()` , `ks.test()` and other test? I am poor in statistical knowledge, please help me out of both the question, thank you!(ps: I have search in the Google and stackoverflow many times, but it does not work, so do not vote this question is useless,Thx!)

Comment: I do not have much reputations to show the pic directly, May someone do me a favor? Thank you for help!

Comment: Please show the code you used for step 5 (i.e. to plot both the data and the curve).

Comment: sorry, I forget it, please check the description again @jbaums

Comment: The questions you pose aren't really within the scope of [so], and really belong on [stats.se]. For your Q1, I think you are confusing relative frequency of discrete bins (a probability mass function) with continuous probability density: see [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/116589/46761), [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/133369/46761), and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/23293/185054) for some discussions. Re Q2, this is not the place for statistical questions (okay if you have a programming question about implementing a specific procedure). Try the folks at [stats.se].

Comment: @jbaums I think Q1 might (just) on topic here, but you are certainly right about Q2; that should be asked on CV.

Comment: @jbaums Thank you, both of you

Comment: @jbaums I have solved my question on CV, thank you for your kind help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, your fitted line seems to be exactly 10 times to high:

```
ggplot() + geom_point(data = t1,aes(x = x,y = y)) +     
  geom_line(aes(x=t1[,1],y=(dgamma(t1[,1],2,0.2))/10),color="red") + 
  theme_classic()
```

gives a perfect fit:
[image]

As jbaums stated this is caused by the density per dx that is 0.1 in this case.

Comment: The density is given as density per dx, and in this case dx is 0.1, since the OP rounded the data to 1 decimal place. In general, `density = count/(sum(count)*binwidth)`.

Comment: @RHA Yeah, I have already tried this method, but just as you said, why?

Comment: @jbaums can you rewrite the code, I can't grasp what you said completely, thank you

Comment: @jbaums the data is mainly used for academic research, so I want to know inner reason, not just for the answer to the question, thank you

Comment: @LingZhang - see my comment on your post.